# Case clause using a view

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to use the Case clause after a view, without success.

I've tried to insert the case clause inside the view but that did not work neither.

```
WITH tgs
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM
         (
             SELECT TGLDATL OperationDate, 
                    TGLVLR UnitPrice, 
                    REPLACE(CONCAT(TGLNCLI, TGLNATR, TGLNSEQ), ' ', '') AccountNumber, 
                    tglctg ProductCode, 
                    tglnopr External_KEY, 
                    tgldmov Description, 
                    tglord
             FROM tgflgmv
             WHERE tglcpr = 'TGCO'
         ) t1
         LEFT JOIN
         (
             SELECT tgcoptxr, 
                    TGCOPTXA TaxCode, 
                    tglnopr, 
                    TGLCCB CCB, 
                    tgcopdmv, 
                    tgcopisn, 
                    TVTAXA TaxAmount
             FROM tgflgmv
                  LEFT JOIN tgfcop ON CONCAT(TGLCTG, TGLORD) = CONCAT(TGCOPCTG, TGCOPORD)
                  LEFT JOIN gbtxref ON TGCOPTXA = TVTTXR
             WHERE tglcpr = 'TGCO'
                   AND tgcoptxr NOT IN('E%', 'CC')
         ) t2 
         ON t1.TGLORD = t2.tgcoptxr
            AND t1.External_KEY = t2.TGLNOPR
         WHERE t2.TGLNOPR IS NOT NULL)
     SELECT CAST(OperationDate AS DATE) OperationDate, 
            UnitPrice, 
            AccountNumber, 
            ProductCode, 
            TaxCode, 
            TaxAmount, 
            Description, 
            External_KEY, 
            CCB
     case
     WHEN TGLCCB LIKE '5%' THEN 'IMPOSTO'
     WHEN TGLCBB LIKE '8%' THEN 'EVENTO'
     ELSE 'NONE'
     END AS CCB
     FROM tgs
     ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: So what's the problem? Why isn't it working? Looks like you're just missing a `,` after the first `CCB` in your final `SELECT`. Also, a `VIEW` can't have 2 columns with the same alias, so you would need to give your `CASE` expression a different alias. These are both just typographical errors.

Comment: new to SQL, my supervisor likes it this way, I don't. Tks for the tip @Larnu! Anyways, I've inserted the ',' and it worked, so many kudos to you. The typo was also corrected

Comment: Bluntly, your supervisor is wrong @mburns ... I really suggest taking Aaron's advise there.

Answer (score -2):

I think it not work for this:

```
 case
 WHEN TGLCCB LIKE '5%' THEN 'IMPOSTO'
 WHEN TGLCBB LIKE '8%' THEN 'EVENTO'
 ELSE 'NONE'
 END AS CCB
```

CASE WHEN bool THEN result1 ELSE result2 END is the structure, you have done:
CASE WHEN bool1 THEN resulta 1 WHEN bool2 THEN result2 ELSE result3 END.

Try:

```
CASE WHEN TGLCCB LIKE '5%' THEN 'IMPOSTO' ELSE
CASE WHEN TGLCBB LIKE '8%' THEN 'EVENTO' ELSE 'NONE'
END END AS CCB
```

Comment: The problem had nothing to do with the **valid** `cASE` expression. A `CASE` expression can have many `THEN` expressions, not just one.

Comment: Have seen it after posting :)